# How is it possible to make a "magic quadrant"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How is it possible to make a "magic quadrant"?

[image]

Comment: Some inspiration: [Help with figures in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20491)/

Comment: More inspiration: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177167/swot-table-how-to-convert-to-an-article/177185#177185, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111278/swot-matrix-using-tikz/111298#111298

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Here's [one we did earlier](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222797/15036)...

Comment: Surely there must be more effective ways of communicating whatever that diagram is meant to communicate than using that diagram to communicate it?

Comment: This is a typical diagram used in Economics or Politics -- colourful, but expressing **nothing**!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my try. I couldn't find the font for the numbers, though, because I prefer the font in your example than the default in Latex.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{lbluew}{RGB}{222,242,252}
\definecolor{dbluew}{RGB}{186,229,250}
\definecolor{lbluef}{RGB}{233,247,254}
\definecolor{dbluef}{RGB}{12,114,184}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw ()
\begin{scope}
\path[clip, preaction={draw, very thick, gray}] [rounded corners=5mm] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\foreach \anch [count=\xi] in {north east, north west, south east, south west}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\filc{int(mod(\xi,1.5)) ? "dbluew" : "lbluew"}
    \node[fill=\filc, anchor=\anch,%
        minimum size=4cm, outer sep=0, inner sep=0] (n\xi) at (0,0) {};
    \node[anchor=\anch, font=\fontsize{60}{22}\selectfont\sffamily, text=lbluef, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] at (0,0) {\xi};

}
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[text=gray!70,font=\large\sffamily]
\foreach \lbla/\lblb [count=\fact starting from 0] in {
    Low/Low,
    Strategic\\business\\value\\provided by information\\security/Effectiness of communicating,
    High/High
}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\addendo{-2+(\fact*2)}
    \node[text width=2cm, align=right, anchor=east] at (-4,\addendo) {\lbla};
    \ifnum\fact=1
    \node at (\addendo,-5) {\lblb};
    \else
    \node at (\addendo,-4.5) {\lblb};
    \fi
}
\end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[text width=3cm,text=dbluef, align=center]
\node[font=\bfseries] (n1) at (-2,2) {Enablement,\\Risk};
\node (n2) at (2,2) {Self improvement imperative for enterprise security leaders};
\node[font=\bfseries] (n3) at (2,-2) {Compliance,\\Cost};
\draw[dbluef, -latex, very thick] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{scope}
\node[align=center,anchor=south, text width=8cm] at (0,4) {Self-improvement for security leaders: Enterprise security professionals need to communicate more effectively about the things that matter most};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit,calc}

\definecolor{lightblue}{HTML}{DEF2FB}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{BCE5FB}
\definecolor{lightbluetext}{HTML}{E6F7FF}
\definecolor{darkbluetext}{HTML}{D3EFFE}
\definecolor{bluetext}{HTML}{2E73A3}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{AFAFAF}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{tikzpicture}[squares/.style={align=center, text width=3cm, text=bluetext, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=4cm}]

    \node[squares,fill=lightblue] (A) at (0,0) {Enablement,\\Risk};
    \node[squares,fill=darkblue,anchor=west] (B) at (A.east) {Self improvement\\imperative for\\enterprise\\security leaders};
    \node[squares,fill=darkblue,anchor=north] (C) at (A.south){};
    \node[squares,fill=lightblue,anchor=north] (D) at (B.south) {Compliance,\\Cost};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,draw=grey,ultra thick,rounded corners=2pt,fit=(A)(B)(C)(D)] {}; 

    \node[text=lightbluetext,anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt,xshift=.4mm,yshift=.2mm] at (A.south east) {\Huge 3};
    \node[text=darkbluetext,anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt,xshift=-.3mm] at (B.south west) {\Huge 4};
    \node[text=darkbluetext,anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt,xshift=.7mm,yshift=-.2mm] at (C.north east) {\Huge 1};
    \node[text=lightbluetext,anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt,xshift=-.4mm,yshift=-.2mm] at (D.north west) {\Huge 2};
    \draw[>=latex,->,color=bluetext,thick] ($(A.east)+(-1,-.1)$) -- ($(B.west)+(1,-.1)$);

    \node[align=center,anchor=south,yshift=2mm] at (A.north east) {Self-improvement for security leaders: Enterprise security\\professionals need to communicate more effectively\\about the things that matter most};
    \node[anchor=east,text=grey,xshift=-2mm] at (A.west) {High};
    \node[anchor=east,text=grey,xshift=-2mm,align=right] at (A.south west) {Strategic\\business\\value\\provided by\\information\\security};
    \node[anchor=east,text=grey,xshift=-2mm] at (C.west) {Low};
    \node[anchor=north,text=grey,yshift=-2mm] at (C.south) {Low};
    \node[anchor=north,text=grey,yshift=-1cm] at (C.south east) {Effectiveness of communicating};
    \node[anchor=north,text=grey,yshift=-2mm] at (D.south) {High};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]